# Why does gcc complain when linking but ld does not?

Tags: gcc, assembly, arm, ld

ARM assembler example file:

```
    .global _start
_start: 
    mov r0, #0x1

    mov r7, #1
    swi 0
```

File can be assembled using either

```
as -o example.o example.s
gcc -c -o example.o example.s
```

And object file can be linked with ld

```
ld -o example example.o
```

But

```
gcc -o example example.o
```

Complains with the following

```
example.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/crt1.o:/build/glibc-6f8a9a/glibc-2.19/csu/../ports/sysdeps/arm/start.S:79: first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9/../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/crt1.o: In function `_start':
/build/glibc-6f8a9a/glibc-2.19/csu/../ports/sysdeps/arm/start.S:119: undefined reference to `main'
```

Background Information:
I am attempting to learn ARM assemble from 'ARM Assembly Language, William Hohl". I have the first edition which uses ARMv4T. I am running code on a Raspberry Pi 1 (ARMv6). So, I am piecing together information from all over the place to try and make the examples run. This one has me stumped. Any pointers in general most appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `s/_start/main/g` clears the `gcc` warnings. The question as to why `ld` could handle the original version remains simply out of interest please.

Comment: Since you don't have a `main` function and you seem to be circumventing the the _C_ runtime and providing your own `_start` label you'll need to tell GCC you don't have a main function and that you aren't using the _C_ runtime. You should be able to add `-ffreestanding` to the GCC options.

Comment: Oh nice answer, thank you. Although, `-ffreestanding`  doesn't help `gcc`

Comment: Try `-nostartfiles -nostdlib`

Comment: you are trying to link both your _start and the one from crt0.o.  see Michael Petch's comment above about no start files, read the gcc help/docs on those options.

Comment: you might want to try linking an assembly function into a C program first rather than a whole program in asm.  easy to control the inputs and outputs and get a lot of learning done.

Comment: Ok, awesome. Thanks allot everyone

Answer (score 0):

Machael Petch is correct in his comments. Using a global called main causes the C runtime to be used to handle program start up and finish.

> We cheated a bit just to make things a bit easier. We wrote a C main
>   function in assembler which only does return 2;. This way our program
>   is easier since the C runtime handled initialization and termination
>   of the program for us.
>   ...
>   This is needed because the C runtime will call main. If it is not
>   global, it will not be callable by the C runtime and the linking phase
>   will fail.

http://thinkingeek.com/2013/01/09/arm-assembler-raspberry-pi-chapter-1/

Comment: While your comment does provide some background, unlike Mr. Petch's comment, you don't actually provide the solution.